# Matlab numeric evaluation of vector function

Tags: matlab, function, vector, eval

I am trying to evaluate a symbolic vector function by plugging in numeric values. After initializing the symbolic vectors, I get values XX1, XX2, XX3, etc...However, when I try to plug in numeric vectors, I get the error: undefined function or variable. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
syms yy
XX = sym('XX', [1 3]);
ww = sym('ww', [1 3]);
f = log(0.5)+log(1+((2*yy-1)*dot(XX,ww))/sqrt(1+dot(XX,ww)^2));
gf = gradient(f,ww);
hf = hessian(f,ww);
%create numeric vectors
X = rand(3,1);
w = rand(3,1);
y = 1;
for (m = 1:length(w))
    XX(m) = X(1,m);
    ww(m) = w(m);
end
yy = y;
eval(gf);
eval(hf);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`matlabFunction`](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) to convert from symbolic functions to numerical functions

```
syms yy
XX = sym('XX', [1 3]);
ww = sym('ww', [1 3]);
f = log(0.5)+log(1+((2*yy-1)*dot(XX,ww))/sqrt(1+dot(XX,ww)^2));
gf = gradient(f,ww);
hf = hessian(f,ww);
%create numeric vectors
X = rand(1,3); %// Note your XX and ww were 1x3 so X and w should be as well
w = rand(1,3);
y = 1;

hfNumerical=matlabFunction(hf,'Vars',{XX,ww,yy})
hfNumerical(X,w,y)

gfNumerical=matlabFunction(gf,'Vars',{XX,ww,yy})
gfNumerical(X,w,y)
```

You have to specify the variables like this so that they stay as vector/matrix inputs.

Answer (score 1):

The error stems from the fact that while you do assign values to the symbolic variables `XX` and `ww`, you don't assign values to the symbolic variables they held.
For example, the variable `XX` initial value is

```
XX =
[ XX1, XX2, XX3]
```

and after your `rand(1,3)` assignment, it has the symbolic components replace with numbers

```
XX =
0.7317    0.6477    0.4509
```

But the values of `XX1`, `XX2`, and `XX3` are still undefined.  You *can* define those values one-by-one and use `eval` **but don't**.

You should either do as @David suggested and make a MATLAB function handle from the output or use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) if you only need to do this once:

```
X = rand(1,3);
w = rand(1,3);
y = 1;
value = subs(gf,[XX,ww,yy],[X,w,y]);
```